# Clustered Table Scan Because of "SELECT *"

Tags: sql-server, index, performance, nonclustered-index, query-performance

I have a `Records` table with over 100 columns and very many rows, and a nonclustered index on 5 fields based on my access paths:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Records_CustomerID]
ON [dbo].[Records] (
    [CustomerID] ASC, -- int
    [IsInvalid] ASC, -- int
    [IsProcessed] ASC, -- bit
    [IsRejected] ASC, -- bit
    [RecordName] ASC, -- varchar(12)
;
```

The 5 fields do not include the primary key `RecordID`, which is the column in the clustered index.

Here is my poorly performing query:

```
SELECT * FROM Records WHERE CustomerID IN (181, 283, 505)
```

The execution plan shows that it performs a Clustered Index Scan, which I understand is because I'm selecting columns that are not included in the index. In Management Studio, I change the query to:

```
SELECT CustomerID, IsInvalid, IsProcessed, IsRejected, RecordName FROM Records 
    WHERE CustomerID IN (181, 283, 505)
```

And the execution plan shows an Index Seek, and the query execution time drops from 44 seconds to 2 seconds. However, I lack the liberty in the application to replace the `*` with only the columns I need and have included in my index.

Is there any way around the clustered index scan when I'm locked into `SELECT *`?

Comment: That is by-design.  It's cheaper to scan the table for all fields than to do 2 operations, one on the index, and one on the table.

Comment: If you care about performance, you'll change the app.  Oh, and "performant" means "one who performs in a play, etc".

Comment: After looking at your Twitter feed I'm fairly certain you already understand the frailty of modern language.  My apologies if I came across as "preachy" with the performant comment.  If you care too, look at this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180410/is-there-a-word-phrase-for-unperformant/180453#180453

Comment: What's in the `IN (…)` subquery?

Comment: As a workaround, can you create a view (with just the 5 columns you need), and then let the app use `SELECT * FROM that_view WHERE CustomerID IN (...);` ?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the IN values. They are literals; there is no subquery.

Comment: @MaxVernon Thank you! "Performant" gets thrown around a lot where I work, now I know! I've revised my wording in the question.

Comment: @MaxVernon Wiktionary agrees with my usage: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/performant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need columns in the output that aren't covered by the index, the optimizer has to make a choice:

1. Perform a table / clustered index scan (therefore all columns are there)
2. Perform a seek, then perform lookups to retrieve the columns not covered

Which way it will choose depends on a variety of things, including how narrow the index is, how many rows match the predicate, etc. You can force a seek with the `FORCESEEK` hint, but I suspect it will end up performing the same or worse than the scan SQL Server has chosen in your case.

Some options:

1. Change the app to run a proper query. [I listed this first for a reason](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).
2. Create a view that selects only the columns you need:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW dbo.myview
   WITH SCHEMABINDING
   AS
     SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM dbo.tablename;
   ```

   Then you can change the app to `SELECT *` from this view. Or you can get even more creative and rename the original table, and change the name of this view to what the name of the table used to be. Breaking change, obviously; proceed with caution.
3. Add all of the other columns to the key or `INCLUDE` list for the index. If these are hard-coded values and *always* the ones used, you may consider a filtered index.

Comment: Thank you and @MaxVernon for the emphasis on the importance of changing the query. I'll get buy-in from my colleagues and make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Having those other fields in the index is just making it worse if you're always using select *. Try creating index just for CustomerID. That might help, but it depends on several things like how many IDs there is in the in list and how many rows per CustomerID there is in the table.